# В памяти процесса хоронить определенную структуру данных

Tags: python

Необходимо в памяти процесса хоронить определенную структуру данных. Если использовать словари как базу - это будет правильно или как правильно делать такие вещи? Redis не предлогать долго работает.

Comment: Я думаю, здесь все зависит от размеров данной структуры и целей ее использования. При определенных условиях, безусловно, можно использовать и словарь, тем более что поиск по ключу достаточно хорошо оптимизирован.

Comment: Размер 10m max, где будет хранит ip,mac,gw,mask. А также lease.db аренда выданных адресов. Поработал с mysql,mongodb но с ними долго, при  условии что все оптимизировано.

Comment: > Необходимо в памяти процесса хоронить определенную структуру данных.

По**хоронить** структуру данных можно, например, так:

    del data